# Better way to aggregate in Polars

Tags: python-polars

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import polars as pl

data = []

measurements = {
    'occupation': [],
    'weight': [],
    'height': [],
    'bmi': [],
    'sugar_level': [],
}

for j in range(1000000):
    weight = random.uniform(50, 100)
    height = random.uniform(4.5, 7)
    bmi = weight / (height ** 2)
    sugar_level = random.uniform(70, 150)
    measurements['occupation'].append(random.choice(['Engineer', 'Doctor', 'Teacher', 'Artist']))
    measurements['weight'].append(weight)
    measurements['height'].append(height)
    measurements['bmi'].append(bmi)
    measurements['sugar_level'].append(sugar_level)

df = pl.DataFrame(measurements)

filter_required = ((pl.col('sugar_level') > 40) & (pl.col('weight') >= 30))
other_filter = ((pl.col('weight') < 60))

groups = (
    df.groupby('occupation')
    .agg(
        q10=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.10),
        q25=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.25),
        q50=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.50),
        q75=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.75),
        q90=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.90),
        q25_sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter).quantile(0.25),
        q50_sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter).quantile(0.50),
        q75_sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter).quantile(0.75)
        ))
```

Above is my snippet, I am applying same filter multiple times inside the groupby and it seems to slow down my computation. I have shown a dummy example. But, my question is is it possible not to use the same filter multiple times inside the groupby? optimized way to do?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of polars? CSE was [added in 0.18.9](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10062/files) which should optimize the filters into a temporary column.

Comment: @jqurious: I am using latest version. Can you please elaborate on CSE? what is it?

Comment: It detects that the 5 `.filter(filter_required)` calls are identical and runs the filter once, storing the value in a temporary column. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10062 is a better link with an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit clunky, but you can

- Aggregate to just a list of the filtered items
- Use `list.eval` to transform the list into a `struct` of the desired quantiles
- (this is the clunky part) the above makes it a one-element list, so need to use `list.first` at this point
- unnest

```py
groups = (
    df.groupby('occupation')
    .agg(
        bmi=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required),
        sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter),
    )
    .with_columns(
        bmi=pl.col('bmi').list.eval(
            pl.struct(
                **{f'q{i}': pl.element().quantile(i / 100) for i in (10, 25, 50, 75, 90)},
            ),
            parallel=True,
        ).list.first(),
        sugar=pl.col('sugar').list.eval(
            pl.struct(
                **{f'q{i}_sugar': pl.element().quantile(i / 100) for i in (25, 50, 75)}
            ),
            parallel=True,
        ).list.first(),
    )
    .unnest('bmi', 'sugar')
)
```

EDIT: Added `parallel=True` on `list.eval` for further speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone can correct me if I'm misunderstanding things:

It is my understanding that Polars should be optimizing this for you as of [v0.18.9](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10062)

If we use a LazyFrame and look at the execution plan:

```py
lf =  (
  df.lazy().groupby('occupation')
    .agg(
        q10=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.10),
        q25=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.25),
        q50=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.50),
        q75=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.75),
        q90=pl.col('bmi').filter(filter_required).quantile(0.90),
        q25_sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter).quantile(0.25),
        q50_sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter).quantile(0.50),
        q75_sugar=pl.col('sugar_level').filter(other_filter).quantile(0.75)
    )
)
print(lf.explain())
```

We can see 2 temporary columns are created that represent the 2 distinct `.filter()` calls inside your aggregation:

```py
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(bmi)!binary: &!binary: >!col(sugar_level)!lit(40.0)!binary: >=!col(weight)!lit(30.0)").quantile().alias("q10"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(bmi)!binary: &!binary: >!col(sugar_level)!lit(40.0)!binary: >=!col(weight)!lit(30.0)").quantile().alias("q25"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(bmi)!binary: &!binary: >!col(sugar_level)!lit(40.0)!binary: >=!col(weight)!lit(30.0)").quantile().alias("q50"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(bmi)!binary: &!binary: >!col(sugar_level)!lit(40.0)!binary: >=!col(weight)!lit(30.0)").quantile().alias("q75"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(bmi)!binary: &!binary: >!col(sugar_level)!lit(40.0)!binary: >=!col(weight)!lit(30.0)").quantile().alias("q90"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(sugar_level)!binary: <!col(weight)!lit(60.0)").quantile().alias("q25_sugar"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(sugar_level)!binary: <!col(weight)!lit(60.0)").quantile().alias("q50_sugar"),
col("__POLARS_CSER_filter!col(sugar_level)!binary: <!col(weight)!lit(60.0)").quantile().alias("q75_sugar")]
```

Comment: Cool I will run a few test case and profile to see if this benefits

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there's much to be gained by doing the filters early.

I had polars v0.18.4 and I did a few benchmarks. The only change I made was to convert the df to lazy and put collect at the end.

The original expression took 47.8 ms ± 3.51 ms per loop

The @Wayoshi expression took 60 ms ± 1.82 ms per loop

Then I upgraded to 0.18.11 and then got...

original expression 50.8 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop

Wayoshi 60.5 ms ± 2.23 ms per loop

The CSE optimization mentioned by @jqurious didn't happen.

I downgraded my polars to specifically 0.18.9. In doing so pip told me that 0.18.9 was yanked but it let me install it. I reran the first expression with explain instead of collect and got the CSE query plan but when I tried to run it with collect it gave a ShapeError. [It appears](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10216) the CSE optimization isn't ready.

To go back to the problem at hand, my idea would have been to filter before the groupby and then join each filter/groupby/agg but the cost of the groupby is so much more than the filter that doing it once for the first filter then again for the second plus the join was just way worse than what was started with. I include that incase anyone has a similar idea, hopefully I can save them some time.